# Why I get undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My application contains a modal, in which I send a variable calls `index`. I can access this variable perfectly in some parts of code but after I closing the modal, my variable becomes undefined. Why this happens?

```
$scope.novoCampo = function (index) {
    //Works
    console.log(index);
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: '',
      resolve: {
        index:  function () {
          return index
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (nomeCampo, index) {
      //I can access 'nomeCampo' but 'index' is undefined 
      console.log(nomeCampo + '\t' + index);
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };

  $scope.toggleAnimation = function () {
    $scope.animationsEnabled = !$scope.animationsEnabled;
  };
```

Modal controller

```
oknok.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, contatosAPI, index){
  $scope.animationsEnabled = true;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    //Works
    console.log('index ' + index);
    $modalInstance.close($scope.nomeCampo, index);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return two items to the promise, simply return one object which contains everything you need, like:

```
$modalInstance.close({nomeCampo: $scope.nomeCampo, index: index});
```

And then in your controller:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (result) {
  console.log(result.nomeCampo + '\t' + result.index);
},
```